# How to calling WCF REST 4.0 from .NET 1.1

Tags: wcf

How to calling WCF REST 4.0 from .NET 1.1.
  I am run into trouble!Any one help me will appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pretty simple. WCF Restful service does not need any mex file to build your proxy client. Call a restful service is same as browsing any URL. You could use HTTPWebRequest class to make  http request for a resource.

See this example at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or at [here](http://dotnetfriendly.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/how-to-consume-net-wcf-rest.html)